# Извиваться и извеваться

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Извиваться или  извеваться? (В руке у него остался изв.вающийся хвост змеи)

Answer (score 2):

Это слово можно проверить без словаря:слово "извИвался" однокоренное со словом "вить", "виться"

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре - извИвался. Рекомендую приобрести орфографический словарь.